# Excluding anything before a certain date in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to build a widget in Confirm Ondemand that displays all our assets that have been inspected and not inspected in a stacked column format, after a certain date. So for example, I would have a column with a location split in two, one colour would be inspected and and another colour would be not inspected. Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT
   feature.site_code,
   feature.plot_number,
   cs.site_name,
   ward.ward_name,
   CASE WHEN feature.survey_date >= to_date('02/10/2017','DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Sprayed'
   ELSE 'Not Sprayed' END as spray_staus,
   feature.survey_date

FROM
   feature,
   ward,
   central_site cs


WHERE
   feature.plot_number BETWEEN 400000 AND 400001 AND
   feature.site_code = cs.site_code AND
   ward.ward_code = feature.ward_code AND
    feature.feature_deadflag ='N'
```

The problem is, I'm getting EVERY inspection from each asset when I only want the latest one.

What do I need to do???

Comment: Which RDBMS used?

Comment: dont use old joins - they nasty and outdated

Comment: You might want to provide some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what RDBMS is used, I want to say Oracle but can't say with certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your question lacks a lot of information.

You should use `ROW_NUMBER()` , but it's hard to say where or how. It should be something like (change it to the table you want the latest record from):

```
FROM
   (SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.YourGroup ORDER BY s.YourDate
    FROM feature s) feature,
   ward,
   central_site cs
....
  AND feature.rnk = 1
```

I used `feature` table for dates, but again, it's only a guess.

Also, this will work for most RDBMS, but not all, so it really depends on it.

Comment: In the end it was the 'feature.plot_number' that did me wrong, the assets I was after are only 400000, while 400001 was something completely different.

Thank you for taking the time to answer me despite doing a terrible job trying to get my question across.

I have a LONG way to go.